# Next JS env variables not working in production

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

According to Next.js documentation, you need to declare your env variables in `next.config.js` under `env` key to read them at build time:

```json
env: {
    GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID
  },
```

This is working correctly in my local environment, the variables are hidden from `_NEXT_DATA` and I can still access them from the client. The problem is when deploying the application for production, it can no longer read from `process.env`. Has anyone encountered this issue?
Note: I don't want to expose sensitive data. Will adding the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to the env variables expose them to `_NEXT_DATA` as well?

Comment: You are probably reading some old documentation. You needn't do anything in `next.config.js` to make env variables work.

Comment: And yes - adding the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix in your `.env` will expose those to the client. Without it, those variables are only available on the server

Answer (score -2):

You should store your env variables in `.env` (for Next.js versions 9.4 and up) file like it's shown [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables). In case you are deploying to Vercel [refer to this guide](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables)